# Combining working queries into one query with multiple columns in result set

Tags: sql, db2

I have 2 basic queries, both working as expected and returning expected results:

```
select
  empNumber,
  sum(salesPrice) as categorySales
from testSchema.sales 
where empNumber = 12345
and date between '2018-01-01' and '2018-04-31'
and g.category = 'NewCategory'
group by empNumber;

select
  empNumber,
  sum(salesPrice) as totalSales
from testSchema.sales 
where empNumber = 12345
and date between '2018-01-01' and '2018-04-31'
group by empNumber;
```

However, I'd like to combine them into one query that returns each result as its own column. The main difference between the 2 queries at the moment is an additional AND clause that creates a specific value. Currently the resuts are

First query:

```
empNumber  |  categorySales
----------------------------
12345               15603.00
```

Second query:

```
empNumber  |  totalSales
----------------------------
12345           350253.00
```

But I'd like to find a performant and expandable way to combine them for this

Desired Result:

```
empNumber  |  categorySales  |  totalSales
-----------------------------------------------
12345           15603.00            350253.00
```

What would be the most performant way to achieve this so that I can add more clauses in the future and return one result set?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? It often does make a difference whether you're using MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server or IBM DB2 - or something else even. Please add a relevant tag to your question!

Comment: Good point, I added the db2 tag for that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to combine both (IF you dont have repeated values)is a FULL JOIN

Try this

```
with c as(
select
  empNumber,
  sum(salesPrice) as categorySales
from testSchema.sales 
where empNumber = 12345
and date between '2018-01-01' and '2018-04-31'
and g.category = 'NewCategory'
group by empNumber
), d as(
select
  empNumber,
  sum(salesPrice) as totalSales
from testSchema.sales 
where empNumber = 12345
and date between '2018-01-01' and '2018-04-31'
group by empNumber
)
Select isnull(c.empNumber,d.empNumber) as empNumber
      ,c.categorySales
      ,d.totalSales
  from c full join d ON (c.empNumber = d.empNumber)
```

Comment: I believe that's exactly what I'm looking for, thank you! Seems to work and I'm applying some other clauses to it as well to test

Comment: I just realized my issue, this is on DB2 which the isnull function will not work with. Is there a better way around that

Answer (score -1):

Include the common conditions in `where` and aggregate conditionally, i.e using a `case` expression.

```
select
  empNumber,
  sum(case when category = 'NewCategory' then salesPrice else 0 end) as categorySales,
  sum(salesPrice) as totalSales
from testSchema.sales 
where empNumber = 12345
and date between '2018-01-01' and '2018-04-30'
group by empNumber;
```